# How to label different objects in a non solid black background?

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy

I know that `scipy.ndimage.label` can't label if the background color is not a solid black.
So I have an image with black background and it's not a solid black so we **can't** assume that all the RGB values are(0,0,0) in all pixels.

How can I prepare the image so I can use `ndimage.label`??

this is a similar image to test on:
[test image http://imageshack.us/a/img4/8661/backgrf.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img4/8661/backgrf.png)
Note:
(1) The image was converted from`RGB` to `PNG gray scale` .
(2) The background color varies.
(3) The `ndimage.label` labels the whole image as one object.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple method for increasing the contrast as far as it can go so that anything "light" becomes white and anything "dark" becomes black. Assuming 8 bit grayscale and adapting the code in @Warren Weckesser's answer:

```
img2 = img.copy()     # Copy the image.
img2[img2 < 128] = 0   # Set all values less than 128 to 0 (black).
img2[img2 >= 128] = 255   # Set all values equal or greater than 128 to 255 (white).
lbl, n = label(img2)
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Yes it works but it is still not general.I thought you would use the histogram to determine that difference you talk about in an automated way.I'm gonna accept your answer anyway.Thanks

Comment: You'd have to have a fairly strange image for it to be worth going to the trouble of a histogram when partitioning into two sets. If you needed more than two sets (like some variation of a posterize/colour quantize algorithm) then it might be a good approach. Glad this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could set all values less than some threshold to 0, and then call label:

```
In [16]: img2 = img.copy()     # Copy the image.

In [17]: img2[img2 < 20] = 0   # Set all values less than 20 to 0.

In [18]: lbl, n = label(img2)

In [19]: n
Out[19]: 2
```

Comment: Nice,but I have to ask is there anyway to determine the proper threshold value automatically??as I can guess you figured out that value through `pylab.hist(ist).am I right?thanks

Comment: Actually, I just looked at the the block img[:5, :5], saw values such as 9 and 10, so I tried 20, and it worked pretty well.  In other words: a lucky guess.  Your idea to use a histogram would probably be a good start towards a method for automatically determining a proper threshold.

Comment: Thanks for your effort.Don't hesitate to post any new ideas.

Comment: Why not split the difference? Essentially that's bumping up the contrast as far as it goes. So if the value is more than half way to black it's black and vice versa.

Comment: @JamieBull You've a point.Why not illustrating you answer in a post so I can accept it.Thanks